# How many comparisons are required?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, sorting

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ integers. Assume you can perform only addition of elements of $S$ and comparisons between sums. Under these conditions how many comparisons are required to find the maximum element of $S$?

I thought that we could find the maximum element as followed:

```
    max=S(1)+S(1)
    k=1
    for j=2 to n
         sum=S(1)+S(j)
         if sum>max
               max=sum
               k=j
    return S(k)
```

That means that $n-1$ comparisons are required.

Is this correct??

Comment: This gives you an upper bound on the number of comparisons, and shows that you need at most $n-1$ comparisons. However, to finish this argument, you also need to show that any algorithm requires at least $n-1$ comparisons.

Comment: @gregkow Why does this give us an upper bound on the number of comparisons??

Comment: Your algorithm is correct. Thus, to find the maximum, using your algorithm will actually work, with $n-1$ comparisons. This shows that we never need more.

Comment: @gregkow Ok!! Does this stand fo any algorithm?? Or only for this specific one??

Comment: This particular algorithm tells us we never need more than $n-1$ comparisons, but doesn't tell us anything else. We want to show that we always need at least $n-1$ comparisons (so for this direction, show that *any* algorithm must take $n-1$ at least, or it will be incorrect).

Comment: @gregkow So, having found an algorithm which requires $n-1$ comparisons, we have to show that a lower bound on the number of comparisons is $n-1$ for any algorithm??

Comment: Exactly! That will give you that the required number is precisely equal to $n-1$, which is what you wanted.

Comment: @gregkow Why does this stand for any algorithm?? Also how can I show that any algorithm requires $\text{ at least }$ $n-1$ comparisons??

Comment: I doubt that they really expected you to show that this algorithm is optimal. Mentioning additions was probably just meant to confuse you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you always put 2 question marks?

Answer (score 2):

To prove $n-1$ is a lower bound, you can make a tree structure.  The leaves are the integers.  Each comparison links the two elements compared and produces a parent that is the greater.  Until you have done $n-1$ the tree cannot have all the leaves, so you don't know which is the greatest.  You need to show that addition can't help.

Comment: This idea only works without allowing addition.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus:  I believe you can show that addition doesn't help, but haven't proved it.  That was the point of the last sentence.

Comment: You certainly can, see my answer. But you need a different argument.

Comment: @RossMillikan Do you mean something like the decision tree??

Comment: Yes.  When you compare elements, with less than $n-1$ comparisons you must have two disjoint trees, so don't know how elements in one compare to elements in the other.  With addition permitted, you might think that you could add the numbers in pairs and compare the total to get away from this.  Yuval Filmus has an example that shows that doesn't help.

Comment: @RossMillikan Could you explain me further the sentence: "When you compare elements, with less than $n−1$ comparisons you must have two disjoint trees, so don't know how elements in one compare to elements in the other." ??

Comment: Let $n=4$ elements be $a,b,c,d$.  If you compare $a$ vs $b$ and $c$ vs $d$, you have one tree with $a,b$ and one with $c,d$.  The largest element overall could be the largest of either tree.  If your first two comparisons were $a$ vs $b$ and $a$ vs $c$, you might know that $a \gt b,c$ but wouldn't know how it compares to $d$

Comment: @RossMillikan So, to prove that a lower bound on the number of comparisons is $n-1$, do we have to say: 

"When we compare elements, with less than n−1 comparisons we must have two disjoint trees, so don't know how elements in one compare to elements in the other." ?? 

Or do we have to say something more?? Or do we have to prove this??

Comment: Yes, that is what I was getting at.  Maybe you already have a theorem that a tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges and vice versa.  Each edge of a tree links the two items you have compared.  With only $n-2$ weighings, you can't have all the weights in one tree.

Comment: @RossMillikan I am looking again at the exercise and I got stuck... Could you explain me again how we use the decision tree to show that a lower bound on the number of comparisons is $n-1$ ??

Comment: $n-1$ is also the lower bound for the case if $n$ is odd, but it seems we don't have the binary tree structure for an odd number of leaves. for an odd number of leaves, would you just use the tree structure for n-1 elements (forget about the last element for now), which will require n-2 comparisons. And then compare the root of this tree with the last element, giving us n-1 comparisons?

Comment: @lamanon:  Not all trees are complete binary ones.  However you do it, if you don't do $n-1$ comparisons there will be one or more elements not compared with the others.  A not more than binary tree with $n$ leaves has $n-1$ non-leaf vertices, which you can prove by induction.

Answer (score 2):

The following argument shows that you need at least $n-1$ comparisons. Suppose that the algorithm only needs $n-2$ (or less) comparisons. Let us simulate it under the assumption that all comparisons end with the result "equal". This gives us $n-2$ equations on the $n$ variables, and so a solution space of dimension 2. The solution space must contain a non-constant vector $v$. In particular, both $v$ and $-v$ are possible solutions, but they have different maximal elements.

To illustrate this bound, let us trace the standard algorithm mentioned by ml0105. The first $n-2$ comparisons give us the equations $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_{n-2} = a_{n-1}$. The solution space is spanned by the vectors $\vec{1} = [1\;1\;\cdots\;1]$ and $v = [0\;0\;\cdots\;0\;1]$. Both $v$ and $-v$ are solutions, but under $v$ only $a_n$ is maximal, while under $-v$ only $a_n$ is *not* maximal. The final comparison eliminates $v$ from the solution space, and the argument breaks down since the solution space consists only of constant vectors, and so all elements are maximal.

Comment: So do we want to show that any algorithm can find the maximum element of a set with at least $n-1$ comparisons?? Could you explain me further how to show this??

Comment: No, we want to show that if an algorithm finds the maximum correctly, then there is some input which causes it to make at least $n-1$ comparisons. Stated differently, any algorithm which makes at most $n-2$ comparisons cannot compute the maximum correctly on all instances.

Comment: Ok!! Could you explain me further how we show that??

Comment: No, I already wrote the argument in the answer.

Comment: You say that we assume that all comparisons end with the result equal, does this mean that we suppose that all the elements are equal?? I got stuck right now...

Comment: The point is that if you make at most $n-2$ comparisons, then it doesn't force all elements to be equal.

Comment: I haven`t understood that... Why does this not force all elements to be equal?? I am confused... :/

Comment: Take your algorithm for example – the first $n-2$ comparisons only force the first $n-1$ elements to be equal. The last element is free.

Comment: Does this mean that if the algorithm uses only $n-2$ comparisons we wouldn't check if the last element is the maximum os $S$??

Comment: No, this was just an example. It could query all elements, but as long as it makes only $n-2$ comparisons, it can't know for sure which elements are maximal.

Comment: By saying that have we shown that a lower bound on the umber of comparisons is $n-1$ ??

Comment: Yes. Any algorithm that always answers a maximal element must sometimes make at least $n-1$ comparisons.

Comment: Ok... Do we have to prove that if it makes only $n-2$ comparisons, it can't know for sure which elements are maximal??

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

The find-max algorithm is pretty standard. I'm not sure why you are using addition operations at all. They are unnecessary.

The algorithm works as follows:

```
findMax(array arr) 
     max := 0

     for i = 1 to arr.length - 1
        if arr[i] > arr[max]
            max := i

     return arr[max]
```

This algorithm uses exactly $n-1$ comparisons.

Comment: How do we know there isn't a better algorithm using some smaller number of comparisons?  That is the point of the comments-you and OP have algorithms that succeed in $n-1$, so that is an upper bound, but there might be a better one out there somewhere.

Comment: I probably should have waited until being more awake before responding. Still, I want to leave my answer, moreso because (1) I don't think it will fit well into a comment, and (2) this algorithm is much more standard, concise, and clear than that in the OP. :-)

Comment: @ml0105 Your algorithm compares the elements to find the maximum, right??? But we assume that we can perform only addition of elements of the set and comparisons between sums...

Comment: @MaryStar A single array element is also a sum, namely a sum of one element. Allowing addition only enlarges the set of operations you're allowed to do.